# adding noise to a video in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, video, augmented-reality, noise, flartoolkit

Before I begin, I would like to apologize if what I'm going to ask is to be considered as super newbie question.

so I was trying out Lee Brimelow's tutorial on creating a simple AR scene using actionscript3. (http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=901)
It worked out pretty well, considering I have never created something out of Adobe Flex Builder before. (I installed Flex Builder right after I saw those tutorial)

here is the source code

```
package {

    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.core.FLARCode;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.core.param.FLARParam;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.core.raster.rgb.FLARRgbRaster_BitmapData;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.core.transmat.FLARTransMatResult;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.detector.FLARSingleMarkerDetector;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.support.pv3d.FLARBaseNode;
    import org.libspark.flartoolkit.support.pv3d.FLARCamera3D;
    import org.papervision3d.lights.PointLight3D;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.shadematerials.FlatShadeMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.utils.MaterialsList;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.Cube;
    import org.papervision3d.render.BasicRenderEngine;
    import org.papervision3d.scenes.Scene3D;
    import org.papervision3d.view.Viewport3D;

    [SWF(width="640", height="480", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]

    public class FLARdemo extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="pat1.pat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private var pattern:Class;

        [Embed(source="camera_para.dat", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private var params:Class;

        private var fparams:FLARParam;
        private var mpattern:FLARCode;
        private var vid:Video;
        private var cam:Camera;
        private var bmd:BitmapData;
        private var raster:FLARRgbRaster_BitmapData;
        private var detector:FLARSingleMarkerDetector;
        private var scene:Scene3D;
        private var camera:FLARCamera3D;
        private var container:FLARBaseNode;
        private var vp:Viewport3D;
        private var bre:BasicRenderEngine;
        private var trans:FLARTransMatResult;

        public function FLARdemo()
        {
            setupFLAR();
            setupCamera();
            setupBitmap();
            setupPV3D();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }

        private function setupFLAR():void
        {
            fparams = new FLARParam();
            fparams.loadARParam(new params() as ByteArray);
            mpattern = new FLARCode(16, 16);
            mpattern.loadARPatt(new pattern());
        }

        private function setupCamera():void
        {
            vid = new Video(640, 480);
            cam = Camera.getCamera();
            cam.setMode(640, 480, 30);
            vid.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(vid);
        }

        private function setupBitmap():void
        {
            bmd = new BitmapData(640, 480);
            bmd.draw(vid);
            raster = new FLARRgbRaster_BitmapData(bmd);
            detector = new FLARSingleMarkerDetector(fparams, mpattern, 80);
        }

        private function setupPV3D():void
        {
            scene = new Scene3D();
            camera = new FLARCamera3D(fparams);
            container = new FLARBaseNode();
            scene.addChild(container);

            var pl:PointLight3D = new PointLight3D();
            pl.x = 1000;
            pl.y = 1000;
            pl.z = -1000;

            var ml:MaterialsList = new MaterialsList({all: new FlatShadeMaterial(pl)});

            var Cube1:Cube = new Cube(ml, 30, 30, 30);                  
            var Cube2:Cube = new Cube(ml, 30, 30, 30);
            Cube2.z = 50
            var Cube3:Cube = new Cube(ml, 30, 30, 30);
            Cube3.z = 100

            container.addChild(Cube1);
            container.addChild(Cube2);
            container.addChild(Cube3);

            bre = new BasicRenderEngine();
            trans = new FLARTransMatResult();

            vp = new Viewport3D;
            addChild(vp);
        }

        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            bmd.draw(vid);

            try
            {
                if(detector.detectMarkerLite(raster, 80) && detector.getConfidence() > 0.5)
                {
                    detector.getTransformMatrix(trans);
                    container.setTransformMatrix(trans);
                    bre.renderScene(scene, camera, vp);
                }
            }
            catch(e:Error){}
        }
    }
}
```

what I am asking is :
is it possible for us to add some noise in the final video output? I'm trying to find out the PSNR by adding noises respectively.
can I do some convolution between the noise and the video?

oh btw I'm doing this for my assignment in college. My prof wanted me to explain how exactly the FlarToolKit works. (details such as Matrix Projections, Obtaining Errors by doing Iterative Method, etc.)

Thank you.
Prama

Comment: thanks Bartzilla for fixing my post! So sorry for being a total noob. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating fine-grained noise dynamically is computationally expensive, so I generate low-res noise and scale it up. In your project, simply add the bitmap setup code after the addEventListener call and then add the single line to generate the noise to your activity loop.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.BlendMode;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class NoiseMain extends Sprite
    {
        protected static const VID_WIDTH : uint = 640;
        protected static const VID_HEIGHT : uint = 480;

        protected static const NOISE_SCALE_X : Number = 4;
        protected static const NOISE_SCALE_Y : Number = 2;

        protected var _vid : Video;
        protected var _noise : BitmapData;
        protected var _composite : BitmapData;
        protected var _matrix : Matrix;

        public function NoiseMain()
        {
            // We're creating a webcam outlet, but not adding it to the stage since we want to post-process the image.
            _vid = new Video(VID_WIDTH, VID_HEIGHT);
            var cam : Camera = Camera.getCamera();
            cam.setMode(VID_WIDTH, VID_HEIGHT, 30);
            _vid.attachCamera(cam);     

            var w : uint = Math.ceil(VID_WIDTH / NOISE_SCALE_X);
            var h : uint = Math.ceil(VID_HEIGHT / NOISE_SCALE_Y);

            _noise = new BitmapData(w, h, false, 0xFFFFFF);
            _composite = new BitmapData(VID_WIDTH, VID_HEIGHT, false, 0x000000);
            var bmp : Bitmap = new Bitmap(_composite);
            addChild(bmp);

            _matrix = new Matrix(NOISE_SCALE_X, 0, 0, NOISE_SCALE_Y);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        protected function enterFrameHandler(evt : Event) : void
        {
            _noise.noise(getTimer(), 204, 255, 7, true);
            _composite.lock();
            _composite.draw(_vid);
            _composite.draw(_noise, _matrix, null, BlendMode.MULTIPLY); 
            _composite.unlock();        
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've revised my example to be more in line with what you're trying to do. You can tweak the noise scale constants to change the "texture" of the noise as well as messing with the strength of the noise (the 2nd and 3rd arguments to the noise() method) and the visual appearance of the noise by changing the BlendMode in the 2nd draw() call).

Comment: Joshua, thank you SO much.  I'm going to try out your code. I'll get back on you if I'm having trouble. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Joshua.. the noise worked pretty well. Thank you.
But I'm worried I've been explaining wrong :

You see, what I want is, the noise would appear when the camera launches - not after the program runs (calculations, transformations, rendering the 3d object, etc).
If the noise appears after the camera launches, hopefully I can find out the noise limitation that my program can tolerate (by adding or reducing the noise). Because my main purpose is I wanted to calculate the PSNR of my program.

I'm so sorry Joshua for the misunderstanding. Can you help me? :( I really appreciate your help. Danke.

Comment: I've updated my code example to be more relevant to what you're doing.

Comment: Once again, thank you SO much, Joshua.. But it still hasn't made my point.. (I'm so sorry Joshua for not explaining it right..)
The noise still appeared at the END of the program. What I was trying to do is: make noise when the camera launches at the BEGINNING of the program. So the image that captured by the camera (which then the image would be calculated and be processed by the program) would have been distorted by the noise that we made..

Is FLARToolKit capable doing such work?

Thank you again Joshua. Thank you so much. And again : I apologize if I bother you with so much questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well, my example WILL take care of what you want to do... simply replace `bmd.draw(vid)` with `bmd.draw(_composite)` (put the contents of my `enterFrameHandler` function before the `draw()` action). Alternatively, you could simply register _composite instead of bmd with FLAR.

Comment: IT WORKED! :D thank you Joshua!
one last question! what is the different between the 2nd and the 3rd arguments in the noise() method? what does the number represent? (as in the unit measurements. is it like, PPI? or DPI?)
thank you so much once again, Joshua. you've been a great helper.

Comment: It's the minimum and maximum luminance values for the noise. In the case of my example: 204-255 or #CCCCCC - #FFFFFF. You can read more about it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#noise%28%29

Comment: thank you Joshua. I have another question I'm asking in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269049/showing-error-value-during-iterative-process-in-order-to-get-the-transformation). This time I was wondering if I could see what was happened inside the FLARToolKit. Are you familiar with FLARToolKit? Thank you again.